# How to prevent users from using 3D Touch peek/preview on anchor tags on my website?

Tags: mobile-safari, 3dtouch

Is there a way to prevent users from using the 3D Touch peek/preview functionality built into Safari when using my website? This functionality isn't useful for, say, anchor elements that run JavaScript.

I'm hoping there's an attribute we can add to  tags to prevent the behavior.

Thanks!

Comment: Or even know if it is happening would be nice.  I used monitorEvents() and no event was fired on the preview triple click (using osx safari)